# Highcharts add line-through to legend text when hidden (itemHiddenStyle)

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for a project at work, and everything works just fine. The only issue is that I wonder if it is possible to add `text-decoration: 'line-through'` to `itemHiddenStyle`.

This is what I have so far:

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        font: '9pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
        color: '#A0A0A0'
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#00ff00'
    },
    itemHiddenStyle: {
        color: '#444',
        //text-decoration: 'line-through' //I would like to add something like this.
    }
}
```

I have only included the relevant code, but if more is necessary, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try doing that? It should work fine.

Comment: @Patel Did you try doing that? It doesn't work.

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes I did. It works. What doesn't?

Comment: Oh, my bad. had to change text-decoration to textDecoration. Yes it works. @Patel you are right.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't think of `textDecoration: 'line-through'`. That works! The issue now, is that when you click on it again (not hidden anymore). The text remains with the `line-through`. Any ideas.

Comment: @cubanGuy I don't think that's necessary. I am glad you worked it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you updated your query, I decided to post this as an answer.

You don't really *need* to go with `textDecoration`. You can stick with `'text-decoration'` but then you'd need quotes obviously.

Once you apply that to `itemHiddenStyle`, it would stay that way even when item is not hidden (after first click).

So, you also need to set `'text-decoration'` back to `none` for `itemStyle`, hence your overall snippet is going to be something like this:

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        font: '9pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
        color: '#A0A0A0',
        'text-decoration': 'none'            /** <---  **/
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
       color: '#00ff00'
    },
    itemHiddenStyle: {
      color: '#444',
      'text-decoration': 'line-through'
    }
}
```

Comment: The only comments is that you have to change it to `textDecoration`. Thanks! Update:Works perfectly with the quotes also.